# Corrupted arguments passed to function

Tags: c, embedded

I am writing an executable for an embedded device (an STM32) in C. After some debugging, I have reduced it to this function:

```
char * parse(char * start)
{
    int i = 0;
    char command[20];
    print(start);
}
```

For some reason, when I call this function, the argument `start` is corrupted. Now I can get it to work if I comment out the `command` initialisation:

```
char * parse(char * start)
{
    int i = 0;
    // char command[20];
    print(start);
}
```

With `command` commented out, it all works fine. I was thing that maybe I might be running out of RAM. But this is program is tiny, and upon checking the stack pointer register, I can confirm that I have a lot of RAM space left.

What could be going wrong here? A broken compiler? (I'm using a recompiled version of GCC for the ARM called Yagarto.)

Comment: What does `print()` do? I suspect your bug might be inside that instead (or it's being fed input it can't handle).

Comment: `print` just prints the string that starts at `start`. But that's irrelevant. GDB shows me that `start` has a different value in both cases when I put a breakpoint.

Comment: What exactly GCC version and compiler/linker flags are you using?

Comment: Note that `parse()` has a return type of `char*`, but does not `return` anything.

Comment: There is a good chance that the bug is somewhere else, and what you see is an issue with GDB: if you do not reference `command` anywhere, the compiler may optimize it out, but GDB may think it's still there. Of course I'm making all of this up, I've never seen something like that, but I think it's a possibility. Try uncommenting the `command` declaration, set its first element to zero, and call `print(start)` to ensure it's not optimized out to verify my "theory" :)

Comment: @hmjd: Yeah, I stripped out as much as I could for debugging.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Still corrupted. :)

Comment: Something is smashing the stack.  When you comment out `command` you are commenting out an allocation of 20 bytes on the stack which means that your stack smashing code is probably vomitting over some different bit of memory.  Post the code for `print()` .  I reckon the bug is in there.

Comment: I guess you should share your `print` implementation, unless it's prohibitively large.

Comment: @Randomblue - Ideally show _all_ the code. If it is big, you could use pastebin, or gist at github. It is extremely unlikely it is the compiler. If you want to reduce that possibility, download LeafLabs Maple IDE, and use the gcc toochain buried in there. Does gdb work o your system? If so, set a data watch on start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely you're in the area of undefined behaviour because you've done something wrong *elsewhere* in your program. The fact that it works under some circumstances in no way makes undefined behaviour acceptable :-)

Possibly, you've overwritten memory or your string is not null terminated, or any of a hundred other reasons.

Answer (score -1):

You somehow destroyed the `parse` function's stack. Commenting out the declaration of `command` variable will remove the allocation on the 20 bytes in your stack that implicitly happens if you keep it.

Can you try **Valgrind** on your program to find out where the corruption happens ?

Also, what is the `print` function ? Try printing the value of `start` in both cases with

```
printf("%p\n", start);
```

You can find the stack of your function in the memory at the address pointed by `parse`

Comment: I don't have a `printf`. I made my own `print` for that reason. I don't have Valgrind, but I do have GDB, if that could help.

Comment: Is the value of `start` changing between _before_ calling `parse` and _inside_ `parse` ?